# bash - Find difference between two variables

Tags: bash, string-manipulation

I have two variables: `var1="1, 2, 3, 4"` and `var2="3, 4, 5, 6"`.
I'd like to get a new one, **var3**, containing the differences between `$var1` and `$var2`.
The expected result should be `var3=1, 2, 5, 6`.

I tried `diff` but the output is not what I wanted:

```
diff <(echo "$var1") <(echo "$var2")
```

```
1c1
< 1, 2, 3, 4
---
> 3, 4, 5, 6
```

Which other solution allows me to have `var3` without creating any file?

Comment: Some additional hints... Enjoy SuperUser and `bash`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways...

- You can use `sort`, `tr` `unique` and `paste` and `$()` to execute them and *"transform the output in a variable"*

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  var1="1, 2, 3, 4"; var2="3, 4, 5, 6"
  var3=$(echo " ${var1}, ${var2}" | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq -u | paste -sd,)
  echo $var3
  ```

  ```
  1, 2, 5, 6
  ```

  For each of the previous commands you can read more with e.g. `man sort`
- You can transform the variable in bash arrays and work on them
  (take the follow just as a hint because there is an uncountable number of ways to realize it...)

  ```
  #!/bin/bash#!/bin/bash
  var1="1, 2, 3, 4"; var2="3, 4, 5, 6"

  # here you transform the variable in array
  IFS=',' read -ra ADDR <<< "$var1"    
  IFS=',' read -ra ADDR2 <<< "$var2"

  # then for each element in the 1st array you search if in the 2nd too
  SEP=""; var3=""
  for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
    Found=0
    for j in "${ADDR2[@]}"; do
        [[ "$i" -eq "$j" ]] && Found=1
    done 
    [[ $Found == 0 ]]  && { var3="$var3$SEP$i" ; SEP=", "; }
  done

  # then for each element in the 2nd array you search if in the 1st too
  for j in "${ADDR2[@]}"; do
    Found=0
    for i in "${ADDR[@]}"; do
        [[ "$i" -eq "$j" ]] && Found=1
    done 
    [[ $Found == 0 ]]  && { var3="$var3$SEP$j" ; SEP=", "; }
  done

  echo $var3
  ```
- using `awk` (or to be precise `gawk`)

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  var1="1, 2, 3, 4"; var2="3, 4, 5, 6"
  var3=$(echo "$var1, $var2" | \
         awk -F ',' '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) {A[$i]++;} } 
                  END{ SEP=""; 
                       for (i in A) {if (A[i]==1){
                          printf ("%s%s", SEP,i); SEP=", "} 
                       }
                     }'
        )
  echo $var3
  ```

**Note:** the second and the third one outputs are not ordered...

---

**Updated Notes**: ...and there is a space before `$var1` and `$var2` because in your *weird* (`:-)`) format there are spaces after the comma (`,`) so you need special care for all the commands that take only one character as separator... this fix the problem if there was an `, 1` in the second string...what are you not able to find with `man <command>` you can try to find with `man bash` or with `help command`...

**Ad nauseam**:

- `diff` style, in the spirit of your attempt... maybe you can search for an output format more cozy (`man diff`)

  ```
  diff --ignore-all-space   \ 
       <(echo "$var1" | tr ',' '\n' ) <(echo "$var2" | tr ',' '\n')\
       | grep -v "^---" | grep -v "^[0-9c0-9]" | tr -d '<||>|| |'  \
       | paste -sd,
  ```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly considering special characters as well.

Comment: @Lejour You're welcome... and welcome on SuperUser. Even the other answers seem to work. Try and upvote the answers you find correct and useful. Choose the one you prefer as _the answer_ for your question and enjoy the site.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time for a full explanation, but:

```
var1="1, 2, 3, 4"; var2="3, 4, 5, 6"
comm -3 <(grep -oP '\d+' <<<"$var1" | sort) <(grep -oP '\d+' <<<"$var2" | sort) |
  tr -d '\t' |
  paste -sd,
```

```
1,2,5,6
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

var1="1, 2, 3, 4"
var2="3, 4, 5, 6"
out=""

for num in `echo $var1,$var2 | tr -d " "| tr "," "\n " | sort | uniq | tr "\n" " "`
do
        if (`grep -v $num <<< "$var1" >/dev/null 2>&1` || `grep -v $num <<< "$var2" >/dev/null 2>&1`)
        then
                out="$out,$num"
        fi
done

echo $out | sed -e 's/,//'
```

And run

```
$ ./test.sh 
1,2,5,6
```